# Approximate the q-function with NN in the FrozenLake exercise

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

```
import numpy as np 
import gym
import random
import time
from IPython.display import clear_output

env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v0")

action_space_size = env.action_space.n
state_space_size = env.observation_space.n

q_table = np.zeros((state_space_size, action_space_size))

num_episodes = 10000
max_steps_per_episode = 100

learning_rate = 0.1
discount_rate = 0.99

exploration_rate = 1
max_exploration_rate = 1
min_exploration_rate = 0.01
exploration_decay_rate = 0.01

reward_all_episodes = []

#Q-learning algorithm
for episode in range(num_episodes):
    state = env.reset()

    done = False
    reward_current_episode = 0

    for step in range(max_steps_per_episode):

        exploration_rate_threshold = random.uniform(0, 1)
        if exploration_rate_threshold > exploration_rate: #Exploit
            action = np.argmax(q_table[state, :])
        else:
            action = env.action_space.sample() #Explore

        new_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

        q_table[state, action] = (1 - learning_rate) * q_table[state, action] + \
            learning_rate * (reward + discount_rate * np.max(q_table[new_state]))

        state = new_state

        reward_current_episode += reward

        if done == True:
            break

    exploration_rate = min_exploration_rate + \
        (max_exploration_rate - min_exploration_rate) * np.exp(-exploration_decay_rate * episode)

    reward_all_episodes.append(reward_current_episode)

reward_per_thousand_episodes = np.split(np.array(reward_all_episodes), num_episodes/1000)
count = 1000
print("Average Reward per thousand episode \n")
for r in reward_per_thousand_episodes:
    print(count, ":", str(sum(r/1000)))
    count += 1000

print("\n ***************Q-table****************\n\n")
print(q_table)
```

I am new in AI and I need a bit of help. I have completed the [FrozenLake exercise](https://gym.openai.com/envs/FrozenLake-v0/) with MVP / Q-learning. Someone told me I can approximate the q-function using a deep neural network. It explains it is called deep Q-learning. How can I improve that code using deep Q-learning and pytorch? In other words, how can I approximate the q-function in using NN here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly broad question, but here's a breakdown.

Firstly NNs are just function approximators.
Give them some input and output and they will find **f(input) = output** 
*Only, if such a function exists and is differentiable based on the loss/cost*

So the Q function is **Q(state,action) = futureReward** for that action taken in that state

**Alternatively,** 
we can change the Q function to take in just the **current state**, and output **an array** of the estimated future rewards for each action. 
Example:

```
[7,5,1,8] for action a,b,c,d
```

So now the Q function => **Q(state)** = **futureRewardMatrix[action*]**

Now all you need is a neural network that takes in the current state and outputs the rewards for each action.*(Only works for discrete actions [a,b,c,d..])*

How to train the network.

- Collect a training batch,by collecting **states,actions,rewards, nextState**
- To get actions you use *nn.predict(state)*, factoring epsilon to choose
  random actions

Training:

```
x_train = state
y_train[action] = reward + self.gamma * (np.amax(nn.predict(nextState))
```

next we train on a relatively large batch of x_trains and y_trains

```
nn.train_on_batch(x_train_batch,y_train_batch)
```

Then repeat the process, of collecting batches for every step of the environment.

I recommend you check out *medium* and *towardsdatascience* DQN articles and their respective Github repos to get full code implementation

Comment: Are you up to show what do I have to modify in my code with explanation? I want to change my code to use deep Q-learning instead of standard MVP/Q-learning. I am very close to understand the differences between Q-learning and deep Q-learning. I have tried to implement Breakout-v0 and CartPole-v0, but it is too hard at the moment. I know that my frozenlake exercise is not worth to use deep Q-learning because the Q-table is way to small, but I think it will just help me to understand better because it is much simpler than CartPole-v0 in my opinion

Comment: Sadly I am not that familiar with PyTorch, but checkout this Keras-TensorFlow implementation https://github.com/tokb23/dqn/blob/master/dqn.py